# Rails: how to halt request cycle in API only application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter

Consider this example in the [official doc](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters):

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_login
 
  private
 
  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access this section"
      redirect_to new_login_url # halts request cycle
    end
  end
end
```

`redirect_to` makes no sense in [api-only application](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html). How can I halt request cycle and respond with custom json or 401 code in API only applications with filters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just doing a render should suffice:

```
class PostsController < ActionController::API # or ApplicationController
  before_action :halt_request

  def index  
    render json: "bravemaster"
  end 

  private 


  def halt_request
    if params[:halt]
      render json: "I stopped"
    end     
  end
end
```

If ActionController detects a response body being set in a callback it will return.

Comment: Thanks. I just found that too. Do you think respond_to or respond_with is better than render?

Comment: ``render`` has a ``:status`` option that lets you specify the HTTP status. So,  ``render json: "message", status: 401`` works. Rails also accepts a set of symbols so ``render json: "message", status: :unauthorized`` works as well. List of HTTP statuses and their symbols can be found here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option

Answer (score 1):

As @Josh's answer says, calling `render` causes Rails to create a response body and terminate the request cycle. By default the HTTP response code is 200, but you can use the `:status` option to specify a different HTTP response code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_login
 
  private
 
  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      render json: 'Unauthorized', status: 401
    end
  end
end
```

Rails also supports a set of pre-defined symbols instead of numerical codes so `status: :unauthorised` is the same as `status: 401`. Check the [documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option) for a list of supported symbols.